# Run terminal command within Tkinter script

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, tkinter

Im using tkinter. How can i pass a terminal command within my code. More specifically, i'd like to run the "chmod +x test.py" command. I have tried "os.system("chmod +x rec.py") with no luck. Thank you.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "no luck"? Do you get an error message saying "no luck"? Does the program crash? Does it seem to work, but the permissions aren't changed? Do you get a stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.chmod('/path/to/rec.py', stat.S_IRWXU)
```

will [add execute permission flag for the owner](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html#stat.S_IRWXU) of `rec.py`. Of course, the user running the script must be a superuser or the owner of `rec.py` in order to change the execute permission flag.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
os.chmod('rec.py',0755)
```